# Bump map painting does not work

Tags: normals, texture-painting

Painting the Bump map does not work in Texture Painting mode. I can see the normals I painted just after rendering, but not in 3D view. For my bump map texture I enabled Geometry Normal and disabled Diffuse Color, but still no bumps in preview. Does anyone got an idea how I can got bumps in 3D preview?[image: Blender 2.69]

Comment: You need to switch the viewport shading to **Texture**, or press **Alt Z** in 3D View.

Comment: @LeonCheung you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to switch the viewport shading to Texture, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in 3D View.

There are generally five things that you should keep in mind to make sure bump effect can be previewed in the 3D Viewport, as shown below:

[image]

Regarding that, you just missed the 4th one. :)

Comment: Hi Leon. Thank you again. Btw great and very clear picture.